# Different topologies with the same continuous real maps

Tags: general-topology

For any topological space $(X,\tau)$, denote $C(X,\tau)$ the algebra of all continuous real-valued functions.

Is the following true or false : 
For any set $X$, and topologies $\tau$, $\tau'$ on $X$ 
such that $C(X,\tau)=C(X,\tau')$, we have $\tau=\tau'$.

If this is false in general, what known topological property on $\tau$, $\tau'$ makes this true ?

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754254/equality-between-rings-of-continuous-functions The exercise originally is from the book Rings of Continuous Functions from L. Gillman.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is open under one of the topologies but not the other. What happens to the characteristic function of $A$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that only shows they have the same *clopen* sets. $\chi_A$ is continuous iff $A$ is clopen in $X$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hmmm... good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\tau$ is the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau'$ the co-countable one, then we have $C(X,\tau)=C(X,\tau')=\{f: X \to \mathbb{R}: f \text{ constant }\}$ (all non-empty open sets intersect in both topologies!) while the topologies are different.

We can conclude it only if $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are completely regular topologies.